# JAVA GWT Timer to fade color of Graphic

Tags: java, gwt, timer, graphic

I am thinking to use two Timers (one to fade towards a color, then one to fade right back to the original color) to create a fading effect on a Graphic. The graphic is built as follows:

```
SimpleMarkerSymbol pointSymbol = SimpleMarkerSymbol.create();
DojoColor color = DojoColor.fromRGB(125, 125, 255);
pointSymbol = (SimpleMarkerSymbol) pointSymbol.setColor(color);
pointSymbol = (SimpleMarkerSymbol) pointSymbol.setSize(6);

SimpleLineSymbol outline = SimpleLineSymbol.create();
color = DojoColor.fromRGB(0, 0, 0);
outline.setColor(color);
pointSymbol.setOutline(outline);
```

I have the following code so far for my fade timers:

```
Timer fadeInTimer = new Timer() {
    int r = 125;
    int g = 125;
    int b = 255;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i<5;i++) {
            r++;
            g++;
            b--;
        }
        DojoColor color = DojoColor.fromRGB(r, g, b);
   }
```

};

```
Timer fadeOutTimer = new Timer() {
    int r = 125;
    int g = 125;
    int b = 255;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i<5;i++) {
           r--;
           g--;
           b++;
         }
         DojoColor color = DojoColor.fromRGB(r, g, b);
    }
};
```

The idea here being that I will call the fadeInTimer x amount of times to change the color significantly (lets say x=25). Then I will call fadeOutTimer x amount of times to return it to the original color. I see that I can schedule a timer for a single occurence via a delay or I can schedule a repeating timer, however I need a repeating timer that will stop running after a given amount of time and I need my fadeOutTimer to wait for the fadeInTimer to complete. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Animations](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwAnimation).

Then, you can easily start a new animation in the `onComplete` method of the first animation.

Comment: can you provide an example of how I would add an animation to a Graphic object

Comment: It's in the link in the answer (_Source Code_ tab).

Comment: this example doesn't animate a Graphic and I don't see where he has a stop condition to know when to stop rotating